# How do I make a scroll bar inside a table as well as make the rows to take 100% of the width

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I'm trying to create a table with 4 columns and at least 12 rows with an **overflow-y:scroll**. The page is fully responsive. I understand that if I need to add a scrollbar to the table I need to make it **display: block** on **thead** as well as tbody. Now the problem that I'm facing is I can't have my trows to have 100% of the width. I've tried to tweak my code for hours now and cannot seem to reach any solution. Attaching the jsfiddle link below

https://jsfiddle.net/kuau4ace/
`
I am only trying to use HTML and CSS with this.

Kindly help!
`<table>`

Answer (score 0):

By making thead and tbody to **display:block** you have changed the property of table,thats why tr don't take width:100%.

**Try this code**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   var body=$('.template_table').clone();
   body.addClass('body');
   $('.table-wrapper').append("<div class='table-body'></div>");
   $('.table-body').append(body);
   var curr = [];
   $("table.body th").each(function(i) {
    var tColumnWidth = $(this).width();
    curr.push(tColumnWidth);
   });
   $("table:first-child th").each(function(i){
     $(this).width(curr[i]);
   });
   $("table.body thead").empty();
   $(".table-wrapper>table tbody").empty();
});
```

```css
.template_table{
    border:1px solid #000;
    width:100%;
    padding: 0;
}
.template_table thead{
    background:#323333;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
}
.template_table tbody{
    height: 210px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.template_table th{
    border:1px solid #000;
    border-left:0;
    border-right:0
}
.template_table th select{
    background:none;
    border:none;
    border-right:1px solid #323232;
    color:#fff;
    padding:5px;
    width:80%;
}
.template_table th{
    width:330px;
}
.template_table th:first-child{
    width:80px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
.template_table th:nth-child(2){
    width:220px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
.template_table td:first-child{
    width:80px;
}
.template_table td:nth-child(2){
    width:220px;
}
.template_table td{
    width:220px;
    color: #c3bfbf;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}
.template_table tbody tr:hover td{
    background:#676767;
    color:#fff;
}

.template_table th{
    border:1px solid #000;
    border-left:0;
    border-right:0;
}
.template_table th select{
    background:none;
    border:none;
    border-right:1px solid #323232;
    color:#fff;
    padding:5px;
    width:80%;
}
.template_table th:first-child{
    width:80px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
.template_table th:nth-child(2){
    width:220px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
.template_table td:first-child{
    width:17%;
}
.template_table td:nth-child(2){
    width:37%;
}
.template_table td:nth-child(3) {

}
.template_table td{
    color:#807c7c;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}
.template_table tbody tr:hover td{
    background:#676767;
    color:#fff;
}
tbody tr{
    cursor:pointer;
    }
.table-wrapper {
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
}
.table-body {
    height: 200px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    width: calc(100% + 15px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-wrapper">
<table class="col-xs-12 template_table">
                                <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th></th>
                                    <th>
                                        <select>
                                            <option>Page Name </option>
                                        </select>
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        <select>
                                            <option>Template</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td>Video Source 1 </td>
                                    <td>Video Clip</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td>ManningL3 </td>
                                    <td>Player L3</td>

                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td>Boyriven </td>
                                    <td>Talent ID</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td>Halftime Stats </td>
                                    <td>Full Screen Stats</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td>Locator </td>
                                    <td>Full Screen Locator</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td>Locator </td>
                                    <td>Full Screen Locator</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td>Locator </td>
                                    <td>Full Screen Locator</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td>Time  </td>
                                    <td>Bug</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td>Singular Info </td>
                                    <td>Topic L3</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td>Los Angeles</td>
                                    <td>Locator</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td>Lewandowski </td>
                                    <td>Player L3</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td>Lewandowski </td>
                                    <td>Player L3</td>
                                </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                            </div>
```

Comment: Your code solves 1 problem, but the scroll is applied to thead as well.
Moreover, hard coding the widths of the th won't make the table responsive.

Comment: hi,please find my updation above.i have written some js to make header fixed.Hope this helps....